# How to calculate this partial sum?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, summation

Why is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{k} \frac{\sin(n \pi)\cos(n \pi t) \sin(n \pi x)}{\pi-\pi n^2}=1/2 \cos(\pi t)\sin(\pi x)?$

How would I calculate this and why is there no $k$ left in the partial sum? My particular problem with this partial sum is that $\sin(n\pi)=0$ for every $n=0,1,2,...k$ and so the whole sum should become $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ a_n := \frac{\sin(n \pi)\cos(n \pi t) \sin(n \pi x)}{\pi-\pi n^2}. $$
If $\,n\,$ is an integer not equal to $1$ then $\,a_n=0.\,$ Also,
$$ \lim_{n\to 1}a_n =1/2 \cos(\pi t)\sin(\pi x). $$ This answers your
question about
$\, \sum_{k=0}^n a_k. $